# Does android support 3g2 file extension?

Tags: android, file-extension

I would just like to ask if android supports 3g2 file extension?
Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
artsylar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See here for a list of supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Different handsets may (and probably do) support others, however that's the authoritative list for avoiding compatibility issues.

Hope this helps,

Phil Lello

Comment: Thanks Phil for your reply. I just noticed in http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html that 3g2 file extension is not listed. As what you have said, maybe some makers just added their support for 3g2 but as for android it is not supported by default.